# Damn Small Linux with XAMPP Linux to create a webserver on a P4 machine or Mele A2000

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, xampp, intel-pentium, damn-small-linux

A couple of days I'am busy to figure out to create a powerful light weight server that can be used as webserver to serve some simple sites that using PHP and mod-rewrite.

The P4-box (actually a laptop, dell latitude c640) i'm using came with windows XP Prof. The problem is that windows consumes more memory and has some TCP/IP stack problems (it is limited) because it can only serve up to 10 (and 40 with a hack) connections a time.

Before this have also bought a Mele A2000 ARM device (china thingy) that comes with Android 4.0, a nice little box that is quiet and is power friendly, just 5 watts. On this device I also tried several things but doens't get ARM linux on it and all software solutions on Android uses Lighttpd which does not support mod rewrite like Apache.

So i start searching the net for a linux distro for the P4-box and found many, to figure out what is the best, it is very difficult for me because of my Windows background (don't want a headless system). Tried several ones and then I found Damn Small Linux (or DSL), looks great and works okay on a very small footprint. Exactly what i'm looking for.

Then I search on DSL+Apache+PHP+mySQL and found the XAMPP Linux version (I use also XAMPP on Windows to test websites, and found a blog that XAMPP must be working on DSL). I found only information how to do it but there is no iso or disk image around with these two worlds combined (at least i didn't find it).

I tried to setup a diskimage (2GB) with use of VMWare, that is working great. The idea is to first try it in VMWare and after that convert the disk to a physical disc without damaging systems or hardware. I have used the DSL install to setup a debian installation (the "install to harddrive" option in the tools menu. Reboot and works okay.

After this i downloaded XAMPP Linux (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html) and follow the instructions on this page. Installed it as superuser but get errors at the install, one about SQL (something with syntax error in a command-line utility) and one error the end (something I didn't understand) but install proceeds and completes.

Then I tried to run 'lampp' or 'xampp' and the only thing I see is floating point exceptions (see image) and doesn't look ok.

[image]

**In short, my questions are:**

- Is there a DSL+XAMPP image around that I can use (can make my life much easier ;-))
- If not, what i'm doing wrong (is it really possible or is there something wrong with the latest version of both?)
- Is there a lightweight distro with XAMPP installed or PHP+Apache+mod_rewrite+mySQL available? ARM or x86?
- Or is it better to take my hands of this and try to figure out to hack windows stack to get more connections
- Or do you have other suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest not using XAMPP, and learning to, and setting it up yourself. I've always had luck with a simple debian or ubuntu server based stack, though I've been using lighttpd/php-fpm based stack these days. Howtoforge has great guides I'd suggest looking at.

Answer (score 1):

DSL is debian based so you can add the Debian or Ubuntu repos, and then then just do the normal stuff.

```
sudo apt-get update <--- after added the repos
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server
sudo apt-get install php5
```

You can add the extensions that you need.

Answer (score 1):

Though a little late, but sounds like ["Lamppix" and "Lamppix Mini"](http://lamppix.tinowagner.com/) is very appropriate for your purposes :

> Lamppix is a Linux Live CD based on Knoppix and Damn Small Linux. It includes Apache, MySQL, > PostgreSQL,PHP, Perl. That means, it includes XAMPP plus PostgreSQL.
>
> Everything is pre-configured, so you can simply insert the CD, reboot
>   and enjoy a running webserver.
>
> You can include your own PHP scripts and they'll run right off the CD.
>   You can even include complete Content Management Systems (CMS) like
>   Typo3 or Mambo to work with them.